# tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority when I use text2vec-openai module in weaviate docker container

Tags: python, docker, ssl, openai-api, weaviate

When I execute below code in operate_weaviate container(python:latest), text2vec-openai module(in weaviate) respond error message.
Please tell me the way to fix this error.

■Code

```
import weaviate

# establish connection
client = weaviate.Client(
    url = "http://xxxxx:8080",
    additional_headers = {
        "X-OpenAI-Api-Key": os.environ.get("OPENAI_APIKEY")
    }
)

# create weaviate class
class_obj = {
    "class": "ManaminaArticle",
    "vectorizer": "text2vec-openai",
    "properties": [
        {
            "dataType": ["text"],
            "name": "sentence",
            "description": "sentence of article",
            "moduleConfig": {
                "text2vec-openai": {
                    "vectorizePropertyName": False,
                    "skip": False,
                }
            }
        }, ...
    ]
}

client.schema.create_class(class_obj)

# batch upload to weaviate
with client.batch as batch:
    batch.batch_size=100

    for i, data in enumerate(manamina_article):
        sentences = split_sentence(data["contents"], 200)

        for sentence in sentences:
            properties = {
                "title": data["title"],
                "url": 'https://manamina.valuesccg.com/articles/' + data["slug"],
                "sentence": sentence,
            }

            client.batch.add_data_object(properties, "ManaminaArticle")
```

■response(error message)

```
{'error': [{'message': 'update vector: send POST request: Post "https://api.openai.com/v1/embeddings": tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority'}]}
```

■environment info
docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.4'
services:
  weaviate:
    command:
    - --host
    - 0.0.0.0
    - --port
    - '8080'
    - --scheme
    - http
    image: semitechnologies/weaviate:1.23.0
    ports:
    - 8080:8080
    - 50051:50051
    volumes:
    - weaviate_data:/var/lib/weaviate
    restart: on-failure:0
    environment:
      OPENAI_APIKEY: ${OPENAI_KEY}
      QUERY_DEFAULTS_LIMIT: 25
      AUTHENTICATION_ANONYMOUS_ACCESS_ENABLED: 'true'
      PERSISTENCE_DATA_PATH: '/var/lib/weaviate'
      DEFAULT_VECTORIZER_MODULE: 'text2vec-openai'
      ENABLE_MODULES: 'text2vec-openai,ref2vec-centroid,qna-openai,generative-openai'
      CLUSTER_HOSTNAME: 'node1'
    networks:
      - gpt-nw

  operate_weaviate:
    build: .
    container_name: operate_weaviate
    volumes:
      - ./xxxx:/xxxx
    working_dir: /xxxx
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    environment: 
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
    networks:
      - gpt-nw

volumes:
  weaviate_data:

networks:
  gpt-nw:
    external: true
```

Dockerfile(for operate_weaviate container)

```
FROM python:latest

ENV CI=true
ENV http_proxy ${proxy}
ENV https_proxy ${proxy}

# Install ping
RUN set -x \
    && apt update -y \
    && apt upgrade -y \
    && apt install -y iputils-ping net-tools \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

COPY ./xxxx /xxxx
COPY ./xxxx/requirements.txt .

WORKDIR /xxxx

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

We tried below command but there was nothing to improve.

1. install ca-certificates

```
$ apt-get install -y ca-certificates openssl
```

2. import open AI root CA using browser and set environment variable "REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE"

```
# add below sentence before data insertion process
os.environ["REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE"] = "../OpenAI_Root.crt"
```

The weaviate module doesn't seem to use Python's "requests" module internally.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I think your ENV http proxy have some problem

Because "https://api.openai.com/v1/embeddings" certificate is correct

```
FROM python:latest

ENV CI=true
ENV http_proxy ${proxy}
ENV https_proxy ${proxy}
```

Check your http proxy or https_proxy server is working properly.

If not using, just get rid of it

Also I'm confused which part is requesting to openapi, and where your proxy is used

Comment: I investigated above problem, I don't guess it's a proxy issue.
When I executed below script which use openai API with curl in same container,
API returned normal answer.

```
$ curl https://api.openai.com/v1/embeddings \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer $OPENAI_API_KEY" \
  -d '{
    "input": "Your text string goes here",
    "model": "text-embedding-ada-002"
  }'
{
  "data": [
    {
      "embedding": [
        ...
        -0.000082575396,
        -0.023988336
      ]
  ...
}
```

Comment: Using curl inside container do not use ENV http proxy as proxy server,
But using python client can use ENV http proxy when request
(If some of your requset library is checking os.env["http_proxy"])

So even though curl request is working, you have to check about env and client code

Comment: Thank you, your advice is helpful for me. However, there was no effect deleting 'http_proxy' and 'https_proxy' before executing method `client.batch.add_data_object()`. I also tried openai embedding API with `curl -x $https_proxy` setting, and it worked well. I can same result when I use openapi embedding API in python script.